# function for counting digits and char in string in Matlab R2015

Tags: matlab, function, char, counting, digits

I have a string inside a cell, for example `'5a5ac66'`. I want to count the number of digits and chars in that string.

`'5a5ac66'`= 4 digits (5566) and 3 chars (aac)

How can I do that? Is there any function in MATLAB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple (not necessarily optimal) solution is the following:

```
digits = sum(x >= '0' & x <= '9');
chars = sum((x >= 'A' & x <= 'Z') | (x >= 'a' & x <= 'z'));
```

Comment: thanks. it works. you answer has less computational burden.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there's a built-in function for that,  [`isstrprop`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html). It tells you which characters are within the given range, in your case `'digit'` or `'alpha'`. You can then use [`nnz`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) to obtain the number of such characters:

```
str = {'5a5ac66'};
n_digits = nnz(isstrprop(str{1},'digit')); %// digits
n_alpha = nnz(isstrprop(str{1},'alpha')); %// alphabetic
```

If you have a cell array with several strings:

```
str = {'5a5ac66', '33er5'};
n_digits = cellfun(@nnz, isstrprop(str,'digit')); %// digits
n_alpha = cellfun(@nnz, isstrprop(str,'alpha')); %// alphabetic
```

Comment: This is a great solution. It also works for non-Western characters.

Comment: @AlexFeinman Thanks for your comment! I didn't know `isstrprop` could do that (although it totally makes sense)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with regular expressions. For example:

```
s = '5a5ac66';
digit_indices = regexp(s, '\d');  %find all starting indices for a digit
num_digits = length(digit_indices); %number of digits is number of indices

num_chars = length(regexp(s, '[a-zA-Z]'));
```

Comment: The other answers here are likely less costly computation wise.